# Apple Pay demo app - Error: 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an app in Swift on my iPhone and after fixing some provisional profile issues I'm running into this error on my main.m file under supporting files.

Here is a code snippet :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/djSbi.png

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint to find out where stuff is actually breaking. To do this, go to the breakpoint menu on the left in xcode (instead of the project navigator or whatever), go to the bottom, hit the +, and click add exception breakpoint, then try running again. Also posting the console output for the error would help more.

Comment: I am on a code page so I don't have the breakpoint menu I don't believe?  Here is my console output: http://i.imgur.com/q0bSo9k.png

Comment: Well first of all, the SIGABRT in main is just what happens when an uncaught exception happens. It has nothing to do with your error. As the console output says, your error is "Application tried to present nil modal view controller on target". To figure out where this is actually happening, you need the exception breakpoint.

Comment: Got it!  http://i.imgur.com/8x4OkqD.png

Comment: What kind of iPhone are you using?

Comment: I am currently using a iPhone 6

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController/initWithPaymentRequest:

In the discussion for this method it says that initialization can fail because the user can't make payments on any of the requested networks.

You should probably check for this using `+ canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:`. Also, on your device, you'll need to setup some credit cards.